# Change the URL to a remote Git repository via Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: git, visual-studio, url, visual-studio-2013, version-control

Is it possible to modify the URL for a remote Git repository via Visual Studio 2013 if it happens to be set incorrectly? I'm getting the "famous" (and not very helpful) error that says:

> "blah, blah...This transport isn't implemented. Sorry."

Is it possible to make this change via the command prompt?

I know the about the command `git remote remove` but the name of the config should follow and I don't know how to determine what it is.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the command line, `git remote set-url remotename url` will do the trick.
docs [here](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)

Answer (score 27):

You might want to open the `.git\config` as a plain file from Visual Studio and edit its contents.

You'll see that there is a section defining the remote called `origin`:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = git://foo.org/blah.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

If you are using HTTPS (SSL) as a transport layer, then you might want to add:

```
[http]
    sslVerify = false
```

if you are using a self-issued SSL certificate on the server.

Comment: great, Pierre, I always prefer manual administration of git things.