# Visual Studio does not recognise repo remote for push/pull/sync

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have a git repo on my local machine at `C:\Git\Foo\` it was originally a clone of my own fork of a project on GitHub.

The repo had two remotes added: my own fork on GitHub (called `origin`) and the original repo it came from, which I called `upstream`.

I noticed, when I had two remotes set-up, that VS would only sync with the `origin` repo, I had to manually `git push`/`git pull` using the Git Bash prompt myself.

I since retired my fork and worked exclusively in the `upstream` repo, and I removed my `origin` remote from the repo. The `upstream` remote is still listed. However now I cannot sync in VS - the Sync, Fetch and Pull buttons are disabled - I have to do everything through the command-line.

Is this a bug? Or by design, does VS only let you sync with the "first" remote?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21576435/visual-studio-2013-how-to-modify-an-existing-remote-repo-url) seems relevant.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't get the same error messages - and after renaming my remotes VS still doesn't pick it up.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio? Over time a lot has changed in the support for multiple repo's. Even between update packs of the same major version.

Comment: What is the repo type? Is it SSH, HTTPS or something else? If SSH, are you on VS2015u2 or higher? If HTTPS is the SSL certificate trusted by your windows machine?

Comment: Did you update your branches so they track `upstream` instead of `origin`?